# AS a facebook group admin, using facebook group api, is it possible to get facebook group members email ids?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

AS a facebook group admin, using facebook group api, is it possible to get facebook group members email ids?

I tried looking at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/groups-api/get-started but it is not clear from there is it is possible to get email ids of members as an admin of the group.

Comment: No you can not get email from group members

Comment: what about if the permissions are set for email access?

Comment: What permission? You need the group members to login to your app and grant email permission to get it.

Comment: Is this correct analysis : step 1: group admin installs the app.  The has set permission as member email access true. Step 2: grouo member joins the group . Since the app had member email access permission is the member notified about it before joining the group to accept the permission as per the app permission requirement ?

Comment: Pretty sure that is not how group apps works. Pretty sure you need a standalone app that the member goes to and grant email permission